# when n is greater than 20 it prints 'weird', but it should print 'not weird'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
N = 24
if N/2 == 0:
    if N in range(2, 5):
        print('Not Weird')
    if N in range(6, 20):
        print('Weird')
    if N > 20:
        print('Not Weird')
if N/2 != 0:
    print('Weird')
```

I want to work it like this:
If N is odd, print Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 6, print Not Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If N is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

Answer (score 3):

You need to use mod operator to check if the number is odd or not.

```
if N % 2 == 0:
    # do something
else:
    # do the other
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `N/2 == 0` will only be true when `N` is zero, you want the modulo operator:

```
if N % 2 == 0:
```

Also, the expression `range(a, b)` gives you an inclusive range of `a` through to `b - 1`, so those `range` calls aren't doing what you think (in any case, they seem to overlap).

I would bypass them anyway and just use more conventional expressions, something like (check the ranges, I've had to make assumptions based on incomplete details in the question - for example, you don't seem to want to print anything for even numbers less that two - you might want to confirm that behaviour):

```
N = 24
if N % 2 == 0:
    if N >= 2 and N < 6: # 2-5 inclusive
        print('Not Weird')
    elif N >= 6 and N < 21: # 6-20 inclusive
        print('Weird')
    elif N > 20:
        print('Not Weird')
else:
    print('Weird')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in this :

1) To check even or odd check if N%2==0, then even else odd.

2) You have used range() function, so if you give number 20, it wont give any output, because 20 is not in range(6,20).

```
N = 20
if N%2 == 0:
    if N >= 2 and N<=5:
        print('Not Weird')
    if N >= 6 and N <= 20:
        print('Weird')
    if N > 20:
        print('Not Weird')
else:
    print('Weird')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
N = 24
if N%2 == 0:  # '%' returns the remainder after floor division
    if N in range(6, 21):  # range(6, 20) excludes 20
        print('Weird')
    else:
        print('Not Weird')  # you can also just use else here
else:  # use else because if it's not even, it is guaranteed to be odd
    print('Weird')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`if __name__ == '__main__':`
`w = 'Weird'`
`nw = 'Not Weird'`

if n%2 == 0:
    if n in range(2,6) or n>20:
        print(nw)
    if n in range(6,21):
        print(w)
else:
    print(w)
```